# Perl extension installation - unable to run nmake

Tags: perl, makefile, perl-module, nmake

I am trying to install a module using cpan on XAMPP.  I am running Windows 7.

Immediately after this prompt is given:

CPAN.pm: Going to build J/JE/JESSE/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.43.tar.gz

It gives the prompt that "The required nmake executable file is not found, and attempts to fetch it.

After this, a popup window appears stating the program "??\c:\xampp\perl\bin\Nmake15.exe can not run due to incompatibility with 64 bit versions of windows.

I downloaded VC++ and copied the make.exe from that install into my perl/bin to replace the original make.exe.  This still didn't work.  Any idea how I can get installations to work with CPAN?

Comment: What Perl are you using?  IIRC ActiveState has its own package manager, and most of the useful stuff from CPAN is prepackaged, i have to assume because of weirdness like this.

Comment: Verified.  Try installing using `ppm`.

Comment: My perl version is 5.10.1.  Do I have to reinstall perl if I get Activestate, and is the PPM free?

Comment: It looks like the version of Perl that comes with XAMPP has `ppm` already.  You should be able to start it from the command line wherever you can run `perl` from.

Comment: Ok - got to ppm - thank you for that.  Attempted to install WWW:Mechanize, and got this error: Can't locate object method "rvalidate" via package "PPM::XML::PPD::html" at C:/x
ampp/perl/site/lib/PPM.pm line 1687, <> line 2.

Answer (score 6):

XAMPP comes with a crippled Perl mostly due to the "Apache Friends" being clueless morons. I suggest installing [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) additionally, then using that installation from your Perl programs. Module installation in Strawberry goes the usual straight way.

Comment: I ended up just installing activestate and copy/pasting the mechanize library from that installation to the xampp perl installation...working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem that the poster, using XAMPP too, and did the following to be able to install modules on windows 7 - 64 bits

Moreover, with this trick you don't have to change path to perl on your perl scripts in windows that were made for most linux servers, this is, keeping #!/usr/bin/perl and use them just from XAMPP locally in your windows box.

- Just as daxim said, get away from XAMPP included perl.
- Download ActivePerl from ActiveState (choose your 32 or 64 bit flavor).
- The package manager GUI is just great (make sure to select View -> All packages, to search..)
- Install the packages you need
- By default ActivePerl installs on C:\perl (or C:\Perl64)
- Use the tool 'reloc_perl' inside "bin" directory to relocate your perl installation to \usr... issuing the following command from "bin" folder: reloc_perl \usr
- Now you can just use #!/usr/bin/perl on your perl scripts using ActivePerl
- If you want to add modules later, you'll have to delete \usr and reloc again, since they get installed on the original directory (which is not deleted by default)

Comment: Correcting myself, I had to finally install a 32 bit version of ActivePerl to be able to use it with XAMPP (as LAMP that comes with it is 32 bits and you have to add .dll files to apache conf to be able to load perl512.dll, mysql.dll from DBD::mysql, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

What @daxim said was true. Use Strawberry Perl 5.14 from http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html. Since a lot of modules were implemented up to that point, you can easily ppm without any needs to add repos.